# Force unwrapping nil optional for UIImageView when transitioning to view controller

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue

I'm running into an error when transitioning to view controllers by overriding the built-in prepare() function in Swift. I have a UIImageView for backgrounds on my screens. Here is the code for two of the view controllers in question.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class HomeVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var signOutButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var friendsNavButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var homeNavButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileNavButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bumpButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var welcomeLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var doNotDisturbLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var doNotDisturbButton: UIButton!
    
    var userName = ""
    var dndIsOn: Bool = false
    
    
    
    @IBAction func dndToggled(_ sender: Any) {
        
        dndIsOn = !dndIsOn
        User.current.available = !dndIsOn
        FirestoreService.db.collection(Constants.Firestore.Collections.users).document(User.current.uid).updateData([Constants.Firestore.Keys.available : !dndIsOn])
        if dndIsOn {
            print("DND is on!")
            setupDNDUI()
            
        } else if !dndIsOn {
            print("DND is off!")
            setupActiveUI()
            
        }
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func signOutTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let firAuth = Auth.auth()
        do {
            try firAuth.signOut()
            } catch let signOutError as NSError {
              print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
        print("Successfully signed out")
    }
    
    @IBAction func bumpTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segues.toCall, sender: self)
        
    }
    @IBAction func friendsNavTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segues.toFriends, sender: self)
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func profileNavTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
        let nav = self.navigationController //grab an instance of the current navigationController
        DispatchQueue.main.async { //make sure all UI updates are on the main thread.
            nav?.view.layer.add(CATransition().segueFromLeft(), forKey: nil)
            nav?.pushViewController(ProfileVC(), animated: false)
        }
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        self.backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        doNotDisturbLabel.isHidden = true
        if !userName.isEmpty {
            welcomeLabel.text = "Welcome Back, " + userName + "!"
        } else {
            welcomeLabel.text = ""
        }
        
    }
    
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .darkContent
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let friendsVC = segue.destination as? FriendsVC else {
            return
        }
        
        FirestoreService.db.collection(Constants.Firestore.Collections.users).document(User.current.uid).getDocument { (snapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                let data = snapshot!.data()!
                let requests = data[Constants.Firestore.Keys.requests] as? [String]
                if let requests = requests {
                    friendsVC.requests = requests
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

```
class FriendsVC: UIViewController {

    //var friends: [Friend] = User.current.friends
    var friends: [User] = []
    var requests: [String]?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var requestsNumberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var friendRequestsButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var homeNavButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var friendsTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var friendTableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var addFriendButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    @IBAction func friendRequestsTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segues.toRequests, sender: self)
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func homeNavTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let nav = self.navigationController //grab an instance of the current navigationController
        DispatchQueue.main.async { //make sure all UI updates are on the main thread.
            nav?.view.layer.add(CATransition().segueFromLeft(), forKey: nil)
            nav?.pushViewController(HomeVC(), animated: false)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        friendTableView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .white
        friendsTitle.isHidden = false

        UserService.getUserArray(uids: User.current.friendUids, completion: { (users) in
            guard let users = users else {
                print("User has no friends")
                return
            }
            
            self.friends = users
            self.friendTableView.reloadData()
            
        })
        
        guard let requests = self.requests else {
            friendRequestsButton.isHidden = true
            requestsNumberLabel.isHidden = true
            self.tableViewTopConstraint.constant = 0
            
            return
        }
        
        requestsNumberLabel.text = requests.count.description
        

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        friendTableView.delegate = self
        friendTableView.dataSource = self
        
        
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let homeVC = segue.destination as? HomeVC {
            
            homeVC.userName = User.current.firstName
            
        } else if let requestsVC = segue.destination as? RequestsVC {
            
            UserService.getUserArray(uids: self.requests!) { (requesters) in
                if let requesters = requesters {
                    requestsVC.requesters = requesters
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

When my app loads into the home screen, there is no problem, and when a button is tapped to transition to FriendsVC, there is no problem. However, when I try to initiate the transition from HomeVC to ProfileVC or from FriendVC to HomeVC, I get the error: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" at the `self.backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill` lines in my viewDidLoad methods. These segues have something in common in that these are the ones where I override the prepare() function, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Why are you not performing segues for going to profile VC?

Comment: Did you test backgroundImageView for nil ? Have you checked you connected properly the IBOutlets to their respective backgroundImageView ? In any case, you should better call self.backgroundImageView?.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill

Comment: @Sweeper I am but just didn't include it here

Comment: @claude31 The backgroundImageView is nil, but only when returning to the HomeVC from the FriendsVC. And yes, all the outlets are properly connected